# ios - music player stops as soon as I enter my app

Tags: ios, audio, avaudiosession, openal

I am tasked to finding why this app stops the Music Player on my ipod. Currently, in XCode, i have set breakpoints in the very first line of `main()`, and still, when i reach that line, the Music Player has already stopped.

I can imagine that any static constructor would have already run, but I've searched for the obvious culprits (any mention of `AVAudioSession`), and found nothing that had run before `main()`.

Since the codebase is just huge, it would be a pain to blindly search for every constructor in every file, without knowing what I'm looking for.
Can you tell me if there is any kind of XCode project property that stops external audio from playing, or anything that I could look for? 
Thanks

EDIT: I've narrowed it down a lot. 
First, for some reason, XCode seems to ignore most of my breakpoints which mislead me completely.
It was indeed a static initialization of an object, which eventually leads to this call:

newDevice = alcOpenDevice(NULL);

For some reason, I can actually get a breakpoint here. Go figure...
So, I have the music playing on this line, but not after I run it. It seems openal's initialization of the device shuts off all external music, for some reason... Trying to understand why, and how can i circumvent it...

Comment: I would search the whole project for the `AVAudioSession`s and then check what the properties are at each stage. You should include when the music player stops happening - for example does it interrupt it upon startup or halfway through its `viewDidLoad` cycle? etc etc

Comment: It gets interrupted during startup, even before main(). I tried setting a breakpoint on the first line of main(), run the app, the music player stopped. I switched to the music player, set it to play, and resumed the app in xcode. The music kept playing. It's just something on startup that's killing the music, and I can't seem to find it...

Comment: Just wanted to clarify... Does the music keep playing after the startup without going back to it? We'll also probably need more code to understand what's going on because for example: `AVCaptureSession`s could interrupt/ignore the `AVAudioSession`.

Comment: No the music does not keep playing after startup. Music player gets stopped. If I switch to the Music Player, press Play, then return to my app, everything works fine. It was just during initialization, the audio device got reset, or something...

Comment: How are you setting up your session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out the problem. For some reason, XCode wasn't helping out. So I had set lots of breakpoints everywhere to see what would run before getting to main. This is where XCode failed me, because I knew the code was running, but for some reason, the breakpoints weren't being triggered. Also, for some reason, others did, so I still have that particular mistery to solve.

Apart from that, the problem was initializing OpenAL just before AVAudioSession got configured with AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient. After switching those two around, everything worked just fine.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Hi Joao, if you're talking about breakpoints, check the project build's scheme to see if it's on debug or release. check exec debug

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for [AVAudioSession's Categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Categories), it sounds like your app has a nonmixable `AVAudioSessionCategory`, can you reproduce if you change it to `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`?

Comment: I set a breakpoint in every call that even remotely mentioned AVAudioSession ( all 57 of them inside Cocos2D ), and none of them are hit. The breakpoint  at the very first line of main is hit ( obviously ) with the music already off. So something before main is killing Music Player.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the music to play on load through the `AppDelegate` ?

Try having it so if the user loads back into the app it continues playing music.